# Google Maps Javascript API Directions quota, usage limit (after june 2016, client-side)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions, google-directions-api, map-directions

I am creating a hybrid mobile application with Google Maps Javascript API v3 and I would like to use the Directions javascript service on client-side.

I just read that the policy of usage changed in june 2016, so now the 2500 daily request quota is valid for the client-side requests as well.

I would like to know if the daily quota can be used up individually in our client's devices or they have to share the quota alltogether.
For example if 3000 customer uses our mobile app on a daily basis than after 2500 of them made a direction request, the other 500 will not be able to do?
The quota number is based on the device or the application?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's now the total across ALL clients.